# “Right Click” keyboard short cut for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-leopard

I am switching back and forth between eclipse and intellij and am really missing the ability to "right click" using the keyboard when I am in eclipse.  I am running OSX Leopard.

Does anyone know if this can be setup in the keys preferences, or is there a plugin that handles simulating a context menu at the current focused component?

Comment: I think we're assuming you're on Windows here. You may want to specify your OS for clarity.

Comment: Good point!  I am looking for a solution for OSX.  That is the real problem, since the keyboard does not have that option in OSX that I can tell.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of Eclipse Juno, Shift+F10 works on Mac to bring up the context menu. It's mapped in Preferences | Keys as Show Context Menu.

Comment: This worked for me. Have an upvote. This should be top answer.

Answer (score 10):

**Windows**

For Windows, I don't think you necessarily need an Eclipse-specific solution. Your keyboard might have a Context Menu key, or you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to bring up the context menu.

[Source](http://www.lytebyte.com/2008/05/29/keyboard-shortcut-to-open-right-click-context-menu/)

**OSX**

After you updated your question to be specific to OSX, I did some searching, and it doesn't seem like there's a built-in OSX way to bring up a context menu. You might be able to find a program that will let you configure keystrokes to simulate mouse clicks, and then configure a shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>.

**Eclipse Configuration**

In `Preferences -> General -> Keys` there are several "Menu" actions that are bindable. Perhaps you can use these? When I filter the options for "Menu", I see, among others:

- Show Refactor Quick Menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
- Show Source Quick Menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
- etc.

Alternatively, you could just find those commands from the context menu that you use most frequently and bind some keyboard shortcuts to them in Preferences -> General -> Keys.

Comment: On OSX, I can't seem to figure out a way to use the keyboard for context menus, in general.  Intellij has a built in solution for context menus.  I was hoping eclipse would also.

Answer (score 6):

On the old Apple branded external keyboards, **the menu button** is to the right of the space bar (<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, on PC style keyboards). Looking at the newer keyboards, and the Mac Book Pros, it doesn't seem to be there (guess it went the same way as the <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> keys).

Having a poke around the **Preferences -> Keys preference page**, I don't think there is a way of revealing the entire context menu.

Many of the sub-menus are available from the keyboard - the ones I have committed to **muscular memory** are:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> - refactoring menu, and the various refactorings available from the keyboard, using the modifiers <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> - Source menu, and various operations beginning with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> - including organize imports, reformat.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> - open type
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - open resource

If all else fails, it is usually worth looking at **<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>** - which shows all current keyboard mappings in a hover on the side of the screen.

With these shortcuts, I would recommend learning one a day. Their culmulative effect is considerable.

I appreciate that this does not answer your question, but I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Click on the trackpad with two fingers, sort of like Moe poking Curly in the eyes.

Comment: right up to the sky with this answer. You´re like an angel to me right now :)

Answer (score 3):

Does your keyboard have a [menu key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)?

Answer (score 2):

While this unfortunately won't provide a solution for your problem I think it's still worth pointing out the following from [The SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#keyboardshortcuts) (Eclipse facilitates [SWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit) to implement its UI):

> **Q: What are the standard keyboard
>   shortcuts on Windows, Mac OS X, GTK?**
>       A: Since SWT uses native controls, standard keyboard shortcuts can be
>   used in SWT applications. Here is a
>   useful [Table of Keyboard Shortcuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts).

Obviously your problem is manifesting itself in row *'Pop up contextual menu for currently selected objects'* of this table, where all platforms but Mac OS do offer either shortcuts <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> or *Menu* or both.

While I can understand that SWT is using the native GUI libraries of the operating system and consequently does not offer this by default, I'm quite surprised that a huge and excellent developer tool like Eclipse is not providing a workaround here. How does IntelliJ solve this issue?

Comment: I can add any key binding I want for the "right" click in Intellij.  Intellij is built on top of Swing, though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know that Windows have a key right between the right Windows key and the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

It is a context menu key.  That may do what you want it to do.

Comment: Many laptops have a Context Menu key, I'm looking at one on mine right now.

Comment: They do, but on vast majority of them it's not located between right control and right windows key - in fact, I'm pretty sure vast majority of them doesn't even have right windows key.

Answer (score -1):

For MacOS try the following, it works like a charm for me

Ctrl + Click